How to determine the behaviour of the intersection operator `&` to add/remove properties?
I'm confused when I try to conclude the behaviour of & operator regarding when it will add/remove properties.
In this example, it removes some properties from the type set of keys:
[K in keyof T & string]: T[K]

The key part is keyof T & string, which removes all non-string keys from the set.

In this example, it adds/combines the properties from the other set:
type Foo = { A: 'a' }
type Bar = { B: 'b' }

type FooBar = Foo & Bar // a variable of this type has both A and B.

As you can see, the & operator behaves differently in the two cases. Why?
On the other hand, the TypeScript compiler just returns me the same type Foo & Bar when I do Foo & Bar, but I would like to know what the resulting set in details, e.g. { A: 'a', B: 'b' } in the second case.

Object types are contravariant in their set of keys. That is, widening the set of keys narrows the object and vice versa. Intersection always narrows. If you use an intersection in the keys you are potentially removing properties while if you use an intersection in the object type itself you are potentially adding properties. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz "widening the set of keys narrows the object and vice versa" Would this be an exception for the vice versa part: { A: 'a' } & { A: 'not_a' }? Could you also extend the explanation regarding the adverb "potentially"? On the other hand, when it's feasible, I want to know whether there is a systematic way to compute the result. (In fact, running typescript compiler does not help, it does not show the resulting set of intersection.)

• The "set of keys" for never isn't well-defined so I don't know if that's an exception or not. • Hmm, you expanded the scope of the question for some reason by asking how to compute the result. Now you're asking two things. Since the second one is "more important" I guess that's your primary question? If so I'll probably close this as a duplicate of this one. If not, please revert that edit and make it ask only the part about explaining &.

Does this answer your question? Is there a difference between Extract and the intersection &?

The new examples require distinct explanations to address, which is more work for us to do. Overall: if you are intersecting two incompatible object types then there will be no value of that type. Whether or not the compiler aggressively reduces that to never is in some sense an implementation detail. & always means intersection and intersection is always a narrowing. Intersections of keys will widen their objects, due to contravariance. Intersection of objects will narrow them, possibly to never. I would write an answer but the existing one is probably good enough, I think.

I mean, this question keeps getting more stuff as time goes on so I think I'm going to disengage; I prefer questions to stabilize and/or narrow in scope in response to comments, not to expand and change.

In both cases, the & intersection operator keeps values that satisfy both type operands.
What may be confusing is that in the second case, it may not be obvious that values that satisfy either Foo or Bar are much more diverse than those that only have keys A or B:
const fooWithAextra = {
    A: 'a',
    Aextra: 0,
} as const

const foo: Foo = fooWithAextra; // Okay, even if it contains more keys

So the set of values that satisfy Foo is very wide: all objects that contain at least key A (with correct value). But only a small subset of those values also satisfy FooBar: objects that contain at least A AND B keys.
We could make the 2nd case apparently closer to the first, if one of the operands had incompatible type with the other operand (like keyof T contains some non-string keys):
type NotBar = { B: 'not B' }
type BarNotBar = Bar & NotBar;
//   ^? never (Bar and NotBar are incompatible)

type Foo2 = Foo | NotBar

type FooBar2 = Foo2 & Bar
//   ^? { A: 'a'; B: 'b'; } (FooBar2 does not accept any NotBar)

So while it looks like & "combines" properties, in fact it just keeps values that have at least ALL properties from both type operands. If some types are incompatible, they are "removed" (like NotBar and non-string keys). If all types are incompatible, you end up with an empty set of values, i.e. never type (like Bar & NotBar).
Playground Link


I would like to know what the resulting set Foo & Bar really is, i.e. { A: 'a', B: 'b' } in the second case.

You can use type-fest Simplify utility type, as done in above playground link:

Useful to flatten the type output to improve type hints shown in editors. And also to transform an interface into a type to aide with assignability.

type FooBar2 = Simplify<Foo2 & Bar>
//   ^? { A: 'a'; B: 'b'; } (not just Foo2 & Bar)

Or the Expand type from jcalz's linked answer: How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?
